# Importing BIG XML file, out-of-line method

Tags: xml, oracle, import, inline

I have a problem with the importing of XML files into a table. These XML files are bigger than 4GB.

We are running the: `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition 11.2.0.4.0 64bit Production`

Our Oracle support said that the problem seems to be due to the inline method which implicates that the maximum total amount of memory consumed by an object instance is 4 GB.

So I should import my XML files using the out-of-line method. I know anything about these methods.

The query I've used to create the table is the one below:

`CREATE TABLE TABLE ( xml_file XMLTYPE ) XMLTYPE xml_file STORE as securefile binary xml;`

According to the documentation and our Oracle support, this is an inline method.

Thus, to load the XML files which are bigger than 4 GB we should create another table dedicated for these files using the out-of-line method.

So that query should be..?

I've been reading all the documentation but probably you can help me in a faster way with your experience as DBA.

Thank you,

Comment: According to this forum post the limit is 2GB/4GB.

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2547698?tstart=0

But your question is unclear because you talk about files >4GB and files >4000 byte. What is it that you want to store?

Comment: It was an error. I mean  file bigger that 4 GB.